# Magento 2 Save product cost per order

Tags: magento2

Our product cost change over time, is it posible to save the product cost in the order. Just as the order save the price. This way I can make reports and know the actual cost and revenue of the order.

Ideally then calling something like this:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
   $sku = $orderItem->getSku();
   $cost= $orderItem->getCost();
   $price= $orderItem->getPrice();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 already has this feature. I was not aware of this when I ask, as I was using getCost(); instead of getBaseCost();

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
   $sku = $orderItem->getSku();
   $cost= $orderItem->getBaseCost(); // This is how is done
   $price= $orderItem->getPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It is possible to save the product cost in the order along with the price. By doing so, you can generate reports and determine the actual cost and revenue of the order. To implement this, you would need to modify your order and order item structures to include the cost information.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to save the cost in the order item:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
   $sku = $orderItem->getSku();
   $cost = $orderItem->getProduct()->getCost(); // Assuming the cost is stored in the product
   $price = $orderItem->getPrice();

   // Save the cost in the order item or any other relevant data structure
   $orderItem->setCost($cost);
}
```

In this example, **$orderItem->getProduct()->getCost()** assumes that the cost information is associated with the product object. You may need to modify this line based on how your data is structured in your application.

By saving the cost information in the order item, you can later retrieve it when needed for generating reports or calculating revenue.

Comment: Thanks, should this go into an observer? What do you think is the best way to implement this?

Comment: use plugin for this as observer is not a good idea in long run, it will retire soon

Comment: I just notice magento was already doing whis with item->getBaseCost(); as before I used getCost() this method was returning cero.